# Log4j2: Logs only to a file, without console?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j2. 
I have two appenders that write logs to two different files, and this works fine.
But these logs also get into the console appender. 
I want to free the console from logs for files, and so that the rest of the logs get to the console. 
How can I do that?

```
# Declare logger
name=LoggingConfig
appenders=a_console, a_test1, a_test2
loggers=l_project, l_test1, l_test2

# Root logger
rootLogger.level=INFO
rootLogger.appenderRefs=a_console
rootLogger.appenderRef.a_console.ref=STDOUT

# Project logger
logger.l_project.name=re.vianneyfaiv.log4j2
logger.l_project.level=DEBUG
logger.l_project.additivity=false
logger.l_project.appenderRef.a_console.ref=STDOUT

# Console logger
appender.a_console.type=Console
appender.a_console.name=STDOUT
appender.a_console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.a_console.layout.pattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) - %m%n

# File logger - 1
appender.a_test1.type=RollingFile
appender.a_test1.name=FILE1
appender.a_test1.append=false
appender.a_test1.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.a_test1.layout.pattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) - %m%n
appender.a_test1.fileName=log4j2-sample-1.log
appender.a_test1.filePattern=log4j2-sample-1-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.a_test1.policies.type=Policies
appender.a_test1.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.a_test1.policies.time.interval=1

logger.l_test1.name=re.vianneyfaiv.log4j2.Log4J2Test1
logger.l_test1.level=ERROR
logger.l_test1.appenderRef.a_test1.ref=FILE1

# File logger - 2
appender.a_test2.type=RollingFile
appender.a_test2.name=FILE2
appender.a_test2.append=false
appender.a_test2.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.a_test2.layout.pattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) - %m%n
appender.a_test2.fileName=log4j2-sample-2.log
appender.a_test2.filePattern=log4j2-sample-2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.a_test2.policies.type=Policies
appender.a_test2.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.a_test2.policies.time.interval=1

logger.l_test2.name=re.vianneyfaiv.log4j2.Log4J2Test2
logger.l_test2.level=INFO
logger.l_test2.appenderRef.a_test2.ref=FILE2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this console logger portion from properties file

```
# Console logger
appender.a_console.type=Console
appender.a_console.name=STDOUT
appender.a_console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.a_console.layout.pattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm add:

```
logger.l_test2.additivity=false
logger.l_test2.additivity=false
```